# How to create document with subcollection in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and I have a question.

Is there a chance to create posts subcollection (default empty) like this:

```
users (collection)
   id (user id auto-generated)
       username
       posts (subcollection)
```

If yes, how to do it. Maybe I missed that topic in docs

```
const userData = {
   username:'test'
}
db.collection('users')
    .doc(id)
    .set(userData).collection('posts')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections are automatically created when the first document is written to them. So if you want to create a `posts` subcollection under the user document, you'll have to write a document to that subcollection.

If you want the user document and post document to be written atomically, you'll have to use a so-called [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Comment: i am intrested in first option, how my code should look?

Comment: There is no different between creating a document in your top-level collection, and creating one in a nested collection. So something like `db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('posts').doc().set(...)` shouild work.